# UK Visa in Old Passport with Maiden Name

Tags: visas, passport-renewals

My visa is in my old passport with my maiden name in it. I was issued a visa in 2014 and there was no BRP at this time yet so I don't have a BRP. I got married and have a new passport. I want to go to holiday outside UK. Shall I apply for a BRP? or can I just show my old passport and new passport? I have informed home office using the change of circumstance form (for visa).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your 2014 visa is still valid, bring the old passport containing that visa, the new passport, of course, and your marriage certificate (to document the change of name).